# How to get back to the redirecting page after login (codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have login controller in my CI app:

```
function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==TRUE) 
        redirect('/success');

    $data['error']=$this->session->flashdata('errormessage');
    $this->load->view('auth',$data);
}

function process_login()
{

    $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');

    if($password == "good_pwd")
    {
    $data=array('username'=>$username,'logged_in'=>TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('/success');   
    }   
    else 
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errormessage','Login failed');
        redirect('/failed');
    }
}
```

Thats my securing constructor in main controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!=TRUE)  redirect('/login');
}
```

When I'm trying to get into www.mysite.com/main/function1/ and I'm not logged in, then constructor redirects me into login page - when I log in correct I'm being redirected into main home page instead of page which redirected me into login page (in this example case: www.mysite.com/main/function1/ ) - how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625556/redirect-to-original-page-after-logging-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you'd need to store your request URI in a session for this, so you can return to the previous page, something along the lines of:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!=TRUE) {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->session->set_userdata('last_page', current_url());
        redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

... you can then use session data to redirect back

Comment: It might be better to use a GET parameter for this, since the session could last for a long time (eg. if the user decides not to connect after all).

Comment: possibly, but sessions in CodeIgniter are being 1. automatically cleared up 2. created with blank parameters even when the user only enters page and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Set the redirection url in the controller of the

```
$redirect_to = "where you want to redirect after login";
$this->session->set_userdata('redirect_to',$redirect_to);
```

Use Some thing like this in the User controller

```
  $redirect_to = $this->input->post('redirect_to') ? $this->input->post('redirect_to') : $this->session->userdata('redirect_to');

    $this->template->build('login', array(
                '_user' => $user,
                'redirect_to' => $redirect_to,
            ));
```