# Back to last two page by controller after submit forms on controller

Tags: codeigniter

For example, when i'm fill the form that i want to submit, and then i want to go back to previous page. This is the code that i'm using to get previous page
`$this->agent->referrer()`
How exactly i get back to second page before since when i'm using the code above, i get back to the form that i have already submit.
I have tried another way like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but i'm still get back to the form page.
Here is the code that I'm currently using :

```
$this->Model->updateDataProducts($id, $data);
$redirect = ($this->agent->referrer());
redirect($redirect);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back to the redirecting page after login (codeigniter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194189/how-to-get-back-to-the-redirecting-page-after-login-codeigniter)

Comment: It's not working too unfortunately ._.

Answer (score 0):

**Set the redirection url in the controller :**

In your redirect call, the second parameter is the "method" of redirection, so that's why your redirect is not working. what you want is something like this:

```
$this->Model->updateDataProducts($id, $data);
redirect('search/my+search+term');  // if you need redirect any methods
```

That's why we do the string concatenation, instead of passing the search term to the second parameter

Comment: It's still not work on me because what I want is after<br>`$this->Model->updateDataProducts($id, $data);`
I want to redirect back to the last 2 page because after I press submit button, the url is changed and if I want to back to the tables that already filtered by id and name : like => `localhost/admin/panel?id=2&name=bob`